# HTML Root Links

Tags: html

I have a **hello.css** in **100-days-of-code** folder as follows :
[Refer here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IONiK.png)

can anyone help me for the href tag to navigate from **Day-5 hello-css.html-->hello.css in parent directory**?

Comment: Please tell us more details, like what have you done, what's your code...

Comment: Are you trying to link the css ?

Comment: Kindly post some of your code then only we can help, also refer to this [ask].

Comment: <link href="../../100-days-of-code/hello.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: I am trying to link the hello.css in 100-days-of-code, I wanted to know the way to write the navigate link for it from a subfolder of the same directory.

Comment: For the css already added the code above in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`../../100-days-of-code/hello.css` should be the path you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../100-days-of-code/hello.css">
```